# Transfer Google Spreadsheet Cell Value generated from ImportRange to another sheet and cell automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have sheet named origin that displays set of data Col A:B via ImportRange
I have a sheet named destination

What I wanted to do:

- When ImportData changes (a new item is added in the origin sheet) I wanted to copy that
  item and paste it in the destination sheet.

What I dont want to happen:

- Is copy data that are already existing in the destination sheet.
- When ImportData Origin is sorted, the display in the origin sheet is
  also changed. In this case I should still be able to copy data that
  are not existing in the destination sheet even if both sheets are no
  longer sorted the same.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?
Thank you so much

Comment: Have you looked at using Apps Script and triggers? See[extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

I would advice you to use a formula in the destination sheet, something like:

`UNIQUE(IMPORTRANGE("url", "origin!A1:B"))`

so you can have the unique items of the `origin` sheet in the destination sheet.

The reason that I am suggesting that is because you are looking for a trigger behaviour. Namely, when a new value is added in a cell, grab this value and send it to another spreadsheet. The problem with this approach is that `Google-Apps-Script` triggers are **not** triggered by scripts nor formulas, but only by **user** edits. In other words, if a cell is modified by your import range formula, there is not a direct `GAS` solution which can figure that out. Only workarounds exist which might have limitations and they are very specific to your exact use case.

### Workarounds

- See [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104025/trigger-function-when-importrange-is-updated) thread for some info and references.
- You can use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) which you can store some sort of data that is bound the script. In this way, you can create a [Time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger which will run every 1 minute or so and check if there are changes to the original data. If a new value is added, update the `property` and send the data to the destination sheet. If no new data is added, do nothing.